# How to edit/add file in VMDK

Tags: linux, virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, mount

I have a VMDK (with several partitions) file which I need to modify. It is not attached to any particular virtual machine.

I've tried using `vmware-mount` (from the VDDK toolset) in on Ubuntu server 12.04 which allows me to mount a particular partition from the VMDK to my local machine. I can successfully view the files and, after changing some permissions, I can write changes to the files.

The problem is that they don't persist after I unmount the vmdk (then remount it to check for the changes). Do I need to do anything before unmounting? I'm currently using `vmware-mount -d` to unmount after making my changes.

I haven't tried to convert the VMDK to a different format, make changes, then convert back. I'm skeptical about going that route.

Comment: What changes do you need to make to it?

Comment: I just need to modify the contents of a text file

Answer (score 3):

You should try [guestfs](http://libguestfs.org/). It supports VMDK format and allows you to change/download/upload content from/to your VMDK file. You can use subcommand `virt-copy-in` to upload content into a disk file, use `virt-edit` to edit file in an offline disk image.

Answer (score 1):

What filesystem is on the vmdk if it's ext2/ext3 then add it to a vm (in persistent mode) find the /dev device for it and mount in linux in the normal way (using mount /mountpoint /dev/[device]) make your changes and then mount /mountpoint

Comment: I would like to do this without any VM's involved. Ideally, I could have a script that makes a simple modification to a bunch of VMDK files.